# The file array not getting set when uploading files having single quote in names

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am building a web application using CodeIgniter framework. The issue is that while uploading a file that have a single quote `'` in the file name (Eg : `Rob's.wmv`) I get an empty file array in the controller. CI do have code to update the file name when the name contains special characters, but since the array is not set correctly the uploading doesn't take place. I can't understand what's going on, I tried debugging, it appears the uploading works fine on my local machine, but not on the server, this makes it even more interesting.

**UPDATE** The file array var_dump returns an empty array, so there's no way I can even get the file name in the script. **The file array is not set, I don't get any information about the file at all.**

Comment: use the php function `addslashes()`. example: `$var = "Rob's.wmv";` then `$var = addslashes($var);`

Comment: @FrayneKonok where ?

Comment: do you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

Comment: Yes I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: do you set the library for uploading the files? helper library?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `addslashes()` from php.
The `addslashes()` function returns a string with backslashes in front of predefined characters.

**example:**

```
$var = "Rob's.wmv"; 
//then 
$var = addslashes($var);
```

The predefined characters are:

```
single quote (')
double quote (")
backslash (\)
NULL
```

Tip: This function can be used to prepare a string for storage in a database and database queries.

**As you upgrade your question:**

please read this two article carefully, this is just a configuration problem. After that i think you are able to do it.

[codeigniter-file-upload](http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-file-upload)

[how-to-upload-file-in-codeigniter](http://code.runnable.com/UhIc93EfFJEMAADX/how-to-upload-file-in-codeigniter)